Ubuntu 24.04 won't boot on Nvidia 960M
After, installing Ubuntu 24.04, the system doesn't boot and it gets stuck on the ASUS bootloading screen:

So you need to force shut down the PC, and after the second time you get the Grub menu, through which you can choose to boot via "recovery mode". So no normal boot is possible, either with Nouveau, Nvidia 470, or 535 drivers.

Did you force it in? Keys should be different. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000144170/how-to-distinguish-the-differences-between-m-2-cards PCIe x2 bus can use both B-keys and M-keys But SATA only SATA bus tend to use B-keys only. Note difference in slots. I Ugraded desktop with NVMe drive from old SATA, but M.2 supported both or had space for both slots. I also have a NVMe drive in an external adapter  ($25) and it works almost as well as an internal SSD with USB3 ports, and when I get newer system with USB-C expect even faster speeds. Better than flash drive as external drive.

M2 SATA and M2 NVME are very different and not interchangeable unless the specs of the system say that it will accept both (not that common). Although I did read a comment that an ADATA XPG SX8200 nvme drive works on that model.
